# What is the difference between the <!-- text --> and /* text */ comments?

Tags: html, comments

What is the difference between the `<!-- text -->` and `/* text */` comments? Are they both the same thing or is there a difference in function?

Comment: Please make clear in what context your comments appear. Maybe add an example.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they're almost the same thing. However, we use `<!--text-->` in HTML and use `/*text*/` in CSS, JavaScript and many others.

Answer (score 2):

`/*` comments are used in C like languages, including Java, JavaScript, and CSS.

`<!--` comments are used in SGML / HTML / XML like languages.

If the language you are considering uses one or both, as long as the language recognizes it as a comment, there's probably not a difference.

The only reason to choose one or the other when designing a language is to for consistency within the language or to avoid syntax constructs that would be better used for something else.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing just depends on the language you are writing code in. Use a code editor like VS code to automatically write comments in whatever detected language by a simple shortcut instead of memorizing.

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers are correct.

As you mentioned the HTML tag in the question so both types of comments syntax can be used for single-line commenting and multi-line commenting but we have to know where we have to use which type of commenting syntax.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hari's demo page</title>
        <style>
            h1 {
                color: blueviolet; /* set h1 color to bv 
                set h2 color to red
                set h3 color to green 
                */
            }
            h2 {    color:chocolate; /* set h2 to chocolate */  }
            h3 {    color: green; /* set h3 to green */  }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--define h1
        define h2
        define h3-->
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
        <h2>Heading 2</h2>
        <h3>Heading 3</h3> /* defined h3 columns */
    </body>
</html>
```

I have used `<!--Content-->` type to single-line as well as multi-line in HTML as you can see in the below image how it is displayed/rendered in the browser.

`/* Content */` is used mostly in CSS, Java, C#, etc., as you can see same in the below image how I included these types of comments in the CSS styling part as well as in the body part (in HTML) and how it is rendered in the browser:

[image]

Comment: Please include your picture as a code example as a "HTML/CSS/Javascript snippet". The OP can then run the code to see the output. Apart from that, your answer does not add anything new to the existing answers, so it is redundant.

Comment: Sure @Klaassiek, updated the answer with code